# Python requests login fails, even with cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm having trouble logging into a website to scrape pages behind login permissions (which I have). I've tried a number of fixes, including using the Requests module (including csrf tokens and hidden tags) and using the BrowserCookie module to try to use cookies from a browser login session. However, nothing seems to work. In the example below, I used a simple requests session. The site returns a 200 code, which supposedly signifies a successful login, but the page redirects back to the login page. Is there anything else I'm missing or is it possible that the website blocks webscrapers from logging in?

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

payload = {
    "UserName":"<user>",
    "Password":"<pass>"
}


s = requests.Session()
r1=s.post("http://<webpage>/login", data=payload)



if r1.status_code == 200:
    print("logged in")
    r2=s.get("<url behind login permissions")
    soup=bs(r2.content,'lxml')
    print(soup.title.string) #Redirects to login page
```

Comment: Typically you have to do a `get()` on the url first, before calling `post()`, to give the site a chance to set up all the cookies.  Also, `post()` calls often return a redirect code such as 302, instead of 200.  Are you sure this particular site returns 200?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I use a 'get()' first, the site returns a 403 error (access denied). Do you think this is a problem I can solve using headers, using other cookies, or is it an indication that this particular site blocks script requests?

Answer (score 0):

Set the session's headers may work, here's an example changing `User-Agent` and `Content-Type`:

```
s.headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
}
```